# Angular 12 how to display dynamically loaded checkbox values in 3 columns?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 12 and "typescript": "~4.3.5". I'm dynamically loading checkbox values. Right now all values are displaying in single column as they load. I need to display them in 3 columns.

```
template:
  LoadControls() {
        const controls = this.options.map(c => new FormControl(true));
        this.ReportsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            options: new FormArray(controls)
        });
  // How does code below works?
    //var groups = asEnumerable(this.options)
    //    .Select((option, id) => { return { option, id }; })
    //    .GroupBy(
    //        x => Math.floor(x.id / 3),
    //        x => x.option,
    //        (key, options) => asEnumerable(options).ToArray()
    //    )
    //    .ToArray();
        this.isFormReady = true;
    }

html:
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-12 control-label margin-bottom">
            Select {{selectedContactStream.HRContactStream}} Assets
        </label>
        <div class="col-4" formArrayName='options'
             *ngFor="let option of optionArrayControl; let i = index">
            <input [formControlName]="i" type="checkbox" /> {{options[i].DataText}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please advise!
p.s. I added some commented code which I found somewhere. I do no know if asEnumerable is part of typescript or linq and what to import to make it work.
UPDATE: I have created a Stackblitz example here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/base-angular-12-app-r8v2dx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: did you try to generate multiple `options` ?

Comment: how to do that? Number of options change based on other selections on form

Comment: if you create me a runnable https://stackblitz.com/ with isolate facing issue, i will be happy to demonstrate how to generate it

Comment: @Yanis-git, Created Stackblitz as suggested by you. Objective is to display dynamically loaded checkboxes in 3 columns. Thx

Answer (score 0):

just for showing you can use the CSS grid. and if you want to use the bootstrap utility class you have to add a parent element with the .row class. you can see the example of both ways.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/base-angular-12-app-9vbgex?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Please post the answer in the answer, rather than as links to external source.